# ORA-00904: invalid identifier when using natural join in the from clause combined with inner joins in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to use a prefix for the city column too (ie: l.city) in the main select statement just like in the inner select sub query statement for a more "understanding" and a better looking way so to speak but i can't because it gives me ORA-00904: "L"."CITY": invalid identifier, using only city without identifier works, why?
This is the code:

```
   SELECT d.department_name, l.city
   FROM  departments d
   NATURAL JOIN (SELECT l.location_id,l.city,l.country_id
                  FROM       locations l
                  INNER JOIN countries c
                  ON (l.country_id = c.country_id)
                  INNER JOIN regions r
                  ON (c.region_id = r.region_id)
                  WHERE r.region_name = 'Europe');
```

Comment: Is l.city a join-condition column? If that's the case, d.city and l.city both are replaced by a "table free" column city. NATURAL JOIN is weird, and I don't like it because the result of a NATURAL JOIN may change if a column is added to one of the tables, and the same column name already exists in the other table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `"L"` alias resides inside the view and is therefore not visible at the place where you want to use it.

Try this:

```
   SELECT d.department_name, x.city
   FROM  departments d
   NATURAL JOIN (SELECT l.location_id,l.city,l.country_id
                  FROM       locations l // <-- "l" has no scope outside brackets
                  INNER JOIN countries c
                  ON (l.country_id = c.country_id)
                  INNER JOIN regions r
                  ON (c.region_id = r.region_id)
                  WHERE r.region_name = 'Europe') x;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just give your subquery an alias or remove the `l.` in `l.city`:

```
SELECT d.department_name, l.city
FROM  departments d NATURAL JOIN
      (SELECT l.location_id,l.city,l.country_id
       FROM locations l INNER JOIN
            countries c
            ON (l.country_id = c.country_id) INNER JOIN
            regions r
            ON (c.region_id = r.region_id)
       WHERE r.region_name = 'Europe'
      ) l
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the 'l' alias in the main query.

```
SELECT d.department_name, subl.city
FROM  departments d
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT l.location_id,l.city,l.country_id
              FROM locations l
              INNER JOIN countries c ON l.country_id = c.country_id
              INNER JOIN regions r ON c.region_id = r.region_id
              WHERE r.region_name = 'Europe') subl;
```